# Long running jQuery method - how to refresh dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

**UPDATE**

I think I have to be a little more precise.

I have this long running code that adds content to my DIVs.
This is an example of the code:

```
m = jQuery('#test').clone();
//do some work
jQuery('#test2').append(m);
```

The Problem is that this can really take a while because sometimes I am adding 100 items. And the content only appears on the page after all 100 items have been added. So the user had to wait like 30 seconds or so.

What I would like to is to update the #test2 - DIV after adding 10 elements or so and then continue adding elements

**Is there a way to refresh the DOM or (better) refresh the test2 - DIV and then continue adding Elements ?**

**OLD Description**

I have a long running jQuery method that clones DIVs and appends them to the page.
It looks like this:

```
m = jQuery('#test').clone();
//do some work
jQuery('#test2').append(m);
```

This code is called several times (sometimes up to 100 times) and it takes pretty long for the content to appear in the page.

Is there a way to refresh the dom and print the content onto the page so that the user is not getting bored because nothing happens ?

Comment: we would need to see a lot more code to advice you on how easy/practical that will be. could be a snap, could be next to impossible. most likely, it's closer to a snap, but who knows?

Comment: How about using a fragment, or a parent element etc. and create the structure before it's appended. Creating the elements shouldn't take long, a few hundred elements would generally only take milliseconds, what's taking long is constantly changing the DOM, which is a horrible way to do things, replace everything in one go.

Comment: I´ve added an update comment ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want using setTimeout. It's like the same logic we use for doing animations.

```
// Code goes here
function load(index) {
    var m = jQuery('#test').clone();
    m.html("Element" + index)
    jQuery('#test2').append(m);

    if(index < 100) {
       setTimeout(function() {
         load(index + 1);
       },100); 
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  load(0);
});
```

here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BHAZjFLbdc79r0bn7XK2?p=preview)

Comment: Hi - forgive my question, but my is a timeout helping in this case ? Doesn´t it delay everything even more ?

Answer (score -1):

This is not exactly what you want, but why don't you put a spinner on your page whilst this is loading, which then goes away when the operations are done? It may be a cleaner method of doing things rather than the page just randomly refreshing for the user whilst they are using it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The crux of the question from what I gathered was what can I do so that the user is not bored when waiting for new content? The author's idea of refreshing the DOM is not good design practice.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you. Your answer showed up in the Low Quality Review queue because someone flagged it. It probably should have been a comment and not an answer.

Comment: OP wants to keep the user from getting bored. It seems totally fair game for an answer to address this at a UX/design level.